# UserMap, getting User NAME instead of ID in Apex

Tags: triggers, apex-code

What if you are trying to populate the Owner Name from a VARIABLE that contains the ID of the user?  How would this one line change?

```
c.MerchantOwner__c = userMap.get(accountMap.get(c.AccountId).OwnerId).name;
```

I tried some variations but can't get it to work.  I ENVISION it being something similar to:

```
accObj.put('xx',  userMap.tmpClosedWonOwner.name );
```

Thanks.   *(this is a cut down version of the code I'm using, hence the diff on the left - I am using a reference to a previous Answer on the first codeset)*

Comment: This was posted in error, now reposted using my proper account.  Plese disregard and my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this select Owner.Name field from Account and populate it to MerchantOwner__c field Something like

for(Account acc: [Select Id,Owner.Name , MerchantOwner_*c  From Account where Id               in:trigger.newMap.keySet() ]){
         trigger.newMap.get(acc.Id).MerchantOwner*_c  =  trigger.newMap.get(acc.Id).Owner.Name;
}